# How to make php command permanent process?

Tags: php

How to make php command permanent process?

lasttime I use the command line to process a php  command. But now  the opening command line is more and more .So I wanna to get a way tp make it process in background and exit the no-echo command line.so how to do that?

Comment: Try something like `nohup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Thinkphp6` Command](https://www.kancloud.cn/manual/thinkphp6_0/1037651)

```php
# \WWW\project\application\admin\command
<?php

namespace app\admin\command;

use think\console\Command;
use think\console\Input;
use think\console\Output;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('test:test')->setDescription('test');
    }

    protected function execute(Input $input, Output $output)
    {
        while(true) {
            // your code
        }
    }

}
```

```php
# \WWW\project\application\command.php
return [
    'app\admin\command\TestCommand',
];
```

[Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) Daemons

```sh
[rogram:test] 
#directory=
command=/www/xxx/php/72/bin/php /www/xxxx/project/think test:test
autostart=true 
autorestart=false 
stderr_logfile=/www/wwwlogs/test_stderr.log 
stdout_logfile=/www/wwwlogs/test_stdout.log
```

start

```sh
supervisorctl start
```